Tailwind config node_modules content property in yarn workspace monorepo
Hi I have a Yarn workspaces moonorepo. My structure is as follows:
node_modules
-- @domain/mypackage
sources
-- app1
-- -- src
-- -- -- components
-- -- -- -- ...
-- -- tailwind.config.js
-- app2

Only app1 has Tailwind components. Now, everything worked fine until I had to pull a non-local package of components named in the example above as @domain/mypackage. I need to add those components too to Tailwind Config's content list from the hoisted node_modules. If it was in local node_modules, adding a path like './node_modules/@domain/mypackage/dist/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}' works (tested on a different codebase). However, what I need it does not work and I cannot figure out how to properly compose the path.
I have tried the following which did not work:
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
   
    // Attempt 1
    '../../node_modules/@domain/mypackage/dist/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',

    // Attempt 2
   path.join(path.dirname(require.resolve('@domain/mypackage/dist/components')), '**/*.{ts,tsx}'),

    // Attempt 3
    path.join(path.dirname(require.resolve('@domain/mypackage')), 'components/**/*.{ts,tsx}'),
  ],

  // ...
};

If it helps, the code is bundled with Vite. Any ideas? 

Silly me had a wrong vite config setting and it was outputting JSX files, which I was not including in 'components/**/*.{ts,tsx}'. It's always true... when something does not make sense, it's usually a typo.
